# JPA/Hibernate avoid multiple instances of an entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA with Hibernate and ran into a problem to have multiple instances of an entity if I load an entity from the database with a new EntityManager/Persistence Context.

A workaround I've found is to use the same Persistence Context for storing and loading an entity. But here I have the problem that this entity is then managed and this will kill my performance. So I need (at most) one instance of my entity and this entity shouldn't be managed.

This is an example code:

```
public static void add(Object o){
     emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("unit");
     entityManager = emFactory.createEntityManager();
     entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
     entityManager.persist(o);
     entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
     entityManager.close();
     emFactory.close();
}

public static List<Object> getAllObjects(String nameOfClass){
    List<Object> objList =  entityManager.createQuery("SELECT i FROM " + nameOfClass + " i").getResultList();
    return objList;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Example s = new Example();
    add(s);
    List<Object> objList = getAllObjects("Example");
}
```

The object I get in my list isn't the same as the one I've stored. If I won't close the entityManager after every insertion then I am getting the same object (that's what I want) but this will kill my performance if the amount of entities and the entities themselves are big.

Is there a possibility to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you elaborate? How come you load a new copy of an existing instance? If you already have an instance, use that. If you need the same instance in another part of your code, your transactions should take care of the integrity of your data. Or mayby I completely misunderstand your question?

Comment: this occurs when I load an entity which has a reference to the entity I have stored in the database. The problem is that the transaction is associated with my EntityManager which I create to store the entity. If I load a new entity which has a reference to the stored one, than I have a new Persistence Context and therefore a new transaction (this is how I have understood transactions), which leads to the problem to have different instances of that entity

Comment: This doesn't seem right. Can you post your code?

Comment: I have had your problem in the past but without code we cannot help you since these problems are very specific to what you want to achieve. In general, one possibility is to put both instances where you load the entity into one transaction. This is however not always a good idea because you want to keep transaction time to a minimum. You should post your code.

Comment: I have posted my code

Comment: 1. you should have one, and only one instance of the EMFactory: it's a heavyweight, thread-safe object. 2. having multiple instances of the same entity is perfectly normal and expected: entities are not thread-safe, and are short-lived. Each transaction should load the entities it needs, work with them, and then forget about them. What are you trying to achieve? The lifetime of an EM is normally the same as the lifetime of a transaction.

Comment: @JB Nizet, If two users request a web page that contains a list of book entities, The Hibernate will instantiate two identical entities lists?

Comment: @Arash it depends on what you mean by "identical". It will create two different list objects, containing different Book objects. But of course, if the database hasn't been modified between the two requests, and the request is the same, the data retrieved by Hibernate will be the same.

Comment: @JB Nizet, Thank you. I got my answer.